# Investigating the cardinality of the set of all subsequences of any arbitrary sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, cardinals

This is a non-precisely formulated question recently come to mind:

How to investigate the cardinality of the set of all subsequences of an arbitrarily given sequence? Or can we possibly determine the cardinality of the set of all subsequences of any arbitrary sequence? (the sequence may be in an (at most) countable set or in an uncountable set)

This question is non-precisely formulated because that there may be at least two ways to define "equivalent" subsequences: (1) two subsequences $(x_{n(j)})$ and $(x_{m(j)})$ are equivalent iff $x_{n(j)}=x_{m(j)}$ for all $j\in\mathbb{N}$ (that is, they have the same value/term in corresponding places of two subsequences), or (2) two subsequences $(x_{n(j)})$ and $(x_{m(j)})$ are equivalent iff $n(j)=m(j)$ for all $j\in\mathbb{N}$ (that is, the two subsequences are chosen from values/terms of the same index in the original sequence.)

In the above two definitions of "equivalent" subsequences, can we and how to investigate the cardinality of the set of all subsequences? Is someone interested to help formulating this question precisely (and maybe edit this post) and to share your viewpoints about this question?

Comment: Unless the sequence is eventually constant, I'm pretty sure there are uncountably many subsequences (with the first equivalence). …With the second equivalence, does it matter what sequence we're considering?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger: I believe that in the second definition of equivalence the cardinality of all subsequences is equal to $|\mathbb{R}|$ since in the original sequence for every index each value/term has two option - be chosen or not. But I have no idea how to deal with the first definition of equivalence...

Comment: Consider the sequence $(0,1,0,1,\dots)$. Can you construct $|\Bbb R|$-many subsequences of that? Consider the sequence $(0,1,2,3,\dots)$. Can you construct $|\Bbb R|$-many subsequences of that?

Comment: For the general case, unless it's eventually constant, I'm pretty sure that it will either (a) have two numbers infinitely often each, or (b) have infinitely many different numbers. (Or both, like $(0,1,2,0,1,3,0,1,4,\dotsb)$.) For those of type (a), use the first example above; for those of type (b), use the second example.